# SQL Update if Column = then Update

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I wrote this query but it gives me incorrect syntax error.  I am trying to update BizValue if BUSINESS_UNIT = 'Value' then update BizValue to 1...

Please help

```
UPDATE products.products 
SET BizValue = CASE BizValue 
        WHEN BUSINESS_UNIT='Optoelectronics' THEN 1
        WHEN BUSINESS_UNIT='Hardware' THEN 2 
        ELSE null
      END
```

Comment: Which sql please? SqlServer?

Comment: it usually helps to include the error message

Comment: thanks will use for future posting

Comment: The type of sql is not relevent in this case.  His syntax is wrong in all of them.

Answer (score 8):

Take out the `BizValue` from the `CASE` part:

```
UPDATE products.products 
SET BizValue = CASE 
        WHEN BUSINESS_UNIT='Optoelectronics' THEN 1
        WHEN BUSINESS_UNIT='Hardware' THEN 2 
        ELSE null
      END
```

or

```
UPDATE products.products 
SET BizValue = CASE BUSINESS_UNIT
        WHEN 'Optoelectronics' THEN 1
        WHEN 'Hardware' THEN 2 
        ELSE null
      END
```